# Linearly evolutive color map

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to create a colormap that should linearly vary according to a "w" value, from white-red to white-purple.

So...

- For w = 1, the minimum value's color (0 for example) would be white and the maximum value's color (+ inf) would be red.
- For w = 10 (example), the minimum value's color (0 for example) would be white and the maximum value's color (+ inf) would be orange.
- For w = 30 (example), the minimum value's color (0 for example) would be white and the maximum value's color (+ inf) would be yellow.

*and so on, until...*

- For w = 100 (example), the minimum value's color (0 for example) would be white and the maximum value's color (+ inf) would be purple.

[image: I used this website to generate the picture https://g.co/kgs/yvqzmr]

I used this website to generate the image : https://g.co/kgs/utJPmw

I can get the first (w = 1) color map by using this code, but no idea on how to make it vary according to what I would like to :

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap
color_map_1 = cm.get_cmap('Reds', 256)
newcolors_1 = color_map_1(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
color_map_1 = ListedColormap(newcolors_1)
```

Any idea to do such a thing in python would be so much welcome,

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you clarify?  Do you want a colormap to depend on two variables, w for hue, and a second variable for the saturation?

Comment: Thank you @JodyKlymak for your answer, I found a satisfying solution ! Just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. Maybe this is not the cleanest way, but it works very well for what I want to do. The colormaps I create can vary from white-red to white-purple (color spectrum). 765 variations are possible here, but by adding some small changes to the code, it could vary much more or less, depending on what you want.

In the following code : using the **create_custom_colormap** function, you get as an output **cmap** and **color_map**. cmap is the matrix containing the (r,g,b) values. color_map is the object that can be used in matplotlib (imshow) as an actual colormap, on any image.

Using the following code, define the function we will need for this job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np      
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, LinearSegmentedColormap

def create_image():
    '''
    Create some random image on which we will apply the colormap. Any other image could replace this one, with or without extent.
    '''

    dx, dy = 0.015, 0.05
    x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, dx)
    y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, dy)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

    extent = np.min(x), np.max(x), np.min(y), np.max(y)

    def z_fun(x, y):
        return (1 - x / 2 + x**5 + y**6) * np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2))

    Z2 = z_fun(X, Y)
    return(extent, Z2)

def create_cmap(**kwargs): 
    '''
    Create a color matrix and a color map using 3 lists of r (red), g (green) and b (blue) values.

    Parameters:
    - r (list of floats): red value, between 0 and 1
    - g (list of floats): green value, between 0 and 1
    - b (list of floats): blue value, between 0 and 1

    Returns:
    - color_matrix (numpy 2D array): contains all the rgb values for a given colormap
    - color_map (matplotlib object): the color_matrix transformed into an object that matplotlib can use on figures
    '''  

    color_matrix = np.empty([256,3])
    color_matrix.fill(0) 
    color_matrix[:,0] = kwargs["r"]
    color_matrix[:,1] = kwargs["g"]
    color_matrix[:,2] = kwargs["b"]
    color_map = ListedColormap(color_matrix)
    return(color_matrix, color_map)


def standardize_timeseries_between(timeseries, borne_inf = 0, borne_sup = 1):
    '''
    For lisibility reasons, I defined r,g,b values between 0 and 255. But the matplotlib ListedColormap function expects values between 0 and 1.

    Parameters:
    timeseries (list of floats): can be one color vector in our case (either r, g o r b)
    borne_inf (int): The minimum value in our timeseries will be replaced by this value
    borne_sup (int): The maximum value in our timeseries will be replaced by this value
    '''

    timeseries_standardized = []

    for i in range(len(timeseries)):
        a = (borne_sup - borne_inf) / (max(timeseries) - min(timeseries))
        b = borne_inf - a * min(timeseries)

        timeseries_standardized.append(a * timeseries[i] + b)

    timeseries_standardized = np.array(timeseries_standardized)
    return(timeseries_standardized)

def create_custom_colormap(weight):
    '''
    This function is at the heart of the process. It takes only one < weight > parameter, that you can chose. 
    - For weight between 0 and 255, the colormaps that are created will vary between white-red (min-max) to white-yellow (min-max).
    - For weight between 256 and 510, the colormaps that are created will vary between white-green (min-max) to white-cyan (min-max).
    - For weight between 511 and 765, the colormaps that are created will vary between white-blue (min-max) to white-purple (min-max).
    '''    
    if weight <= 255:
        ### 0>w<255
        r = np.repeat(1, 256)

        g = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        g = standardize_timeseries_between(g, weight/256, 1)
        g = g[::-1]

        b = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        b = standardize_timeseries_between(b, 1/256, 1)
        b = b[::-1]

    if weight > 255 and weight <= 255*2:
        weight = weight - 255

        ### 255>w<510
        g = np.repeat(1, 256)

        r = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        r = standardize_timeseries_between(r, 1/256, 1)
        r = r[::-1]
        
        b = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        b = standardize_timeseries_between(b, weight/256, 1)
        b = b[::-1]

    if weight > 255*2 and weight <= 255*3:
        weight = weight - 255*2

        ### 510>w<765
        b = np.repeat(1, 256)

        r = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        r = standardize_timeseries_between(r, weight/256, 1)
        r = r[::-1]
        
        g = np.arange(0, 256, 1)
        g = standardize_timeseries_between(g, 1/256, 1)
        g = g[::-1]


    cmap, color_map = create_cmap(r=r, g=g, b=b)

    return(cmap, color_map)
```

Use the function **create_custom_colormap**  to get the colormap you want, by giving as argument to the function a value between 0 and 765 (see 5 examples in the figure below):

```
### Let us create some image (any other could be used).
extent, Z2 = create_image()

### Now create a color map, using the w value you want 0 = white-red, 765 = white-purple.
cmap, color_map = create_custom_colormap(weight=750)

### Plot the result
plt.imshow(Z2, cmap =color_map, alpha=0.7,
           interpolation ='bilinear', extent=extent)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: Example cbars]